# I want to get Shipping methods and tax by zipcode search on product view page in Magento2.1.6

Tags: php, knockout.js, magento2

I want a zip code functionality on product view page like checkout page summaries. But i've slightly confusing on Magento2's knockout js.

[image]

Can u please tell me anyone, that where the price of shipping rate like flatrate, freeshipping..etc. Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid it's very unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: i want a zipcode search functionality on product view page sir.